# Как отключить отмену прокрутки страницы (скролл)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Добрый день! При открытии страницы по умолчанию есть условие отмены скролла.

```
function OffScroll () {
var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).bind('scroll',function () {
  $(window).scrollTop(winScrollTop);
});}
OffScroll ();
```

Как при нажатии на блок `<div class="open">Блок</div>` восстановить возможность прокрутки страницы? Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) вам в помощь:

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

**UPD**. Добавил пример:

```js
function OffScroll() {
  var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(winScrollTop);
  });
}

OffScroll();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.open').click(function() {
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="open">Unbind</button>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: @LADYX, добавил пример, посмотрите, прокрутка запрещается в окне "Результат" и по кнопке снова работает, а у в коде судя по всему не хватает `$(window)` перед `unbind()`

Comment: @LADYX, данная функция не восстанавливает функции скролла, а отменяет все обработчики скролла, которые вы вешаете на окно